# Why my Crystal Report is displaying blank?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Question sir,

I'm using VS 2012 with crystal report. Why my report show blank data, I've used ado.net dataset object to create a crystal report. When i ran it. It showing blank. is there anyway to fetch the data inside the dataset to use to crystal report?

Comment: Make sure that the data is actually present in DB. If u r sure of having the data, then try displaying that data in a 'gridview control' by assigning it the ado.net dataset that you have used.. If this works, then the data should definitely be displayed in your Report.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I have it displayed in a datagrid view. But in crystal report its blank. is there any code that i can use to send the data in dataset to crystal report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way that i prefer to display tha data in a Crystal Report using code, than following 'wizards' to configure that report.

```
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
    using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

    private void LoadDataIntoReport()
    {
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    DataSet ds=this.GetFilledDataSet();// trigger the method below that returns the DataSet
    rptDoc.Load("<<THE PATH OF THE .rpt FILE>>");
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
    }
    private DataSet GetFilledDataSet()
    {
    // code here, to fetch the data from the Database and fill it into the DataSet
    // return the DataSet
    }
```

Try out with this one !!